# ViewPager Automatic Partial Swipe

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I have got three pages in my viewpager and by default i have to set the middle one. But for the first time I want to swipe the viewpager a little left and then right to indicate to a user that there are also two more pages, left and right to it. Please guide regarding the automatic partial swipe of viewpager.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

please refere this sample code.In this example you will get how to do automatic swipe of viewpager.

> https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

before using this library i also have some problem when i use pager.

Comment: I did it by using a custom scroller to slow down animation a little bit and then calling pages using setCurrentItem(position) from left to right using a handler.postDelayed and adjusting them with proper time delays according to my need.